# I want to update an output list every 1 second using setInterval(), but it gets infinity loop output

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to update my list of name every 1 second so i try setinterval() but it gets loop. any solution?

```
 <script>
 getcus();
 function getcus(){
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $.get('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/get_all_customer_ajax', function (data) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(data)
          for (var i=0;i<obj.customer.length;++i)
          {
          $('#names').append(obj.customer[i].first_name + "<br>");
          }
    });
 });
   setInterval(getcus, 1000);
  };
```

output

Maria
Jose
Clark
Maria
Jose
Clark
Maria
Jose
Clark
Maria
Jose
Clark

to infinity..

Comment: You never stop the interval, what do you expect? Use `clearInterval(interval)` to clear the interval

Comment: you're also appending to what is already there. you should clear `#names` each time first.

Comment: @ElefantPhace i see, how can i clear it?

Comment: swap `setInterval` with `setTimeout` You make exponential number of call this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty the #name div before append to it
setTimeout the getfocus function, because it call itself so you dont need setInterval in this case. use setTimeout in success callback to make sure next request will call after first request is success

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  getcus();
});

function getcus(){
  $.get('<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/site/get_all_customer_ajax', function (data) {
   var obj = JSON.parse(data);
   $('#names').empty();
   for (var i=0;i<obj.customer.length;++i)
   {
    $('#names').append(obj.customer[i].first_name + "<br>");
   }
          setTimeout(getcus, 1000);
 });
 
};
```